# BigInteger(String) and BigInteger(byte[]) are not equal

Tags: java, arrays, byte, biginteger

I was expecting the two constructors in the BigInteger class, `BigInteger(String)` and `BigInteger(byte[])`, to behave similarly but they don't.

Why are the two BigInteger not equal? How can I create a `BigInteger` from the byte array?

```
String hex = "94B4";
byte[] b = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(hex); // -108, -76

BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger(hex, 16); //38068
BigInteger b2 = new BigInteger(b); //-27468
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the `byte[]` constructor treats input as regular 2's complement data, whereas the hex constructor treats it as, well, a hex string.

Using the `new BigInteger(int signum, byte[] magnitude)` allows you to force the value to be positive, so `new BigInteger(1, b)` will be `38068`.

Answer (score 1):

It will come as no surprise that 38068 + 27468 is 65536.

Remember that a `java.lang.String` is an array of characters, and a `char` in Java is an *unsigned* 16 bit type. Nice.

`BigInteger b2 = new BigInteger(b);` circumvents that. It interprets the data as a 2's complement *signed* 16 bit type.

Hence the difference.